# .ajax() "GET" within an .ajax() "GET" , ajax call now showing correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I have two ajax calls, but for some reason one of the ajax isn't working as planned.

one ajax call is getting data from a site `ajax1.php`, and then another ajax is getting data from `ajax2.php` and its supposed to change some data within `ajax1.php`.

So I have `index.php` and the ajax goes something like this

This is `index.php`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other,
        url: "ajax1.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#div").html(data);

    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id_1="+id+"&id_2="+id_2,
        url:"ajax/ajax2.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#change_data").html(data);

    });

<div id="div">
<div id="change_data"><!-- This div is supposed to be in ajax1.php so it only appears after the first ajax is done.!--></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that #change_data isn't showing up correctly. It shows what its supposed to for a second, then disappears. Not sure what the problem is. I tried putting a delay : `$("#change_data").delay.(1000).html(data_changed);` like so, but doesnt work. I tried putting the whole ajax function inside the first .done() ajax function, but that doesn't work.

It might be because when the first ajax loads, the second ajax tries to load faster than the first ajax. The first ajax has a lot more information so it may need to load a little longer?

Any ideas? Thanks Maybe there's another way to put the second ajax within the first so on success, it'll call the second ajax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Maybe there's another way to put the second ajax within the first so on success, it'll call the second ajax?

Yes, there is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other,
    url: "ajax1.php"
}).done(function(data){
    $("#div").html(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id_1="+id+"&id_2="+id_2,
        url:"ajax/ajax2.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#change_data").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: @drew010, Looks like I'm not! :( I just saw this comment on his code: `<!-- This div is supposed to be in ajax1.php so it only appears after the first ajax is done.!-->`

Comment: @bfavaretto, yeah #change_data is in `ajax1.php` and I want to change data in there

Answer (score 3):

$.ajax call is asynchronous, so the first call is not guaranteed to be complete by the time the second call happens. You should make the second call inside the callback for the first call, something like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other,
        url: "ajax1.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#div").html(data);


        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: "id_1="+id+"&id_2="+id_2,
           url:"ajax/ajax2.php"
        }).done(function(data){
           $("#change_data").html(data);
        });

});
```

Comment: yeah, i figured, but I havn't had the experience to know what I could do in such a way? I just tried putting the whole ajax function within the first ajax function, but the second ajax doesn't call? Is it supposed to work, and I probably just have to fix some other stuff?

Comment: I just edited my response - it is supposed to work, I use such ajax call in ajax call in some places in my own code